# Finding a Riemann integral

Tags: integration, analysis, proof-verification, riemann-integration

I'm trying to solve this Riemann integral$\int^{\frac {\pi}{2}}_0 x \,d\sin(x) $ using the theorem* but I don't know if apply the theorem in the correct form.

We have that $F(x)=\int^{\frac {\pi}{2}}_0 x \,d\sin(x)$. Then $F'(x)=\frac {\pi}{2} (\sin x)'=\frac{\pi}{2} (\cos x)$.

Is my answer correct? Is there another way to calculate the integral?

Theorem*: Let $\alpha\in BV([a,b])$ and $f\in R(\alpha)$ in $[a,b]$ and $f$ continuous in x$\in (a,b)$. Then

a) If $\alpha$ is continuous in $c$, then $F$ is defined by F(x)= $\int^x_a f(t) \, d\alpha(t)$ is continuous in $c.

b) $F\in BV([a,b])$

c) if $\alpha$ is differentiable over $(a,b)$ then $F'(x)=f(x)\alpha'(x)$.

NOTE: Here BV means bounded variation and $R(\alpha)$ means riemann integrable over function $\alpha$

Comment: Now the theorem* is complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to solve
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\mathrm d\sin x=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\cos x\mathrm dx
$$
which can be done by parts to find 
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\mathrm d\sin x=\frac{\pi}{2}-1$$

Comment: Won't I use my Theorem* then?

Comment: If you are trying to find $F'(x)$ sure. But if you are trying to find $F(\pi/2)-F(0)$, which is the integral you have said you want to evaluate, you must compute the above

Comment: ok, but my professor said there are two ways of computing the integral, and the result will only differ by a constant.

Comment: I'm not sure what was meant without context

Comment: he just said 'find the integral using the theorem'. Before this theorem we proved the mean value theorem for Riemann-Stieltjes integrals